# CodeIgniter: Upload data from excel intp existing MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, excel, codeigniter

i want to upload data to my database from excel two times (from separate excel files)

Like this, my table:

```
id | name | address | account | note
```

and this is the first excel data:

```
id | name | address
```

Second Excel

```
account | note
```

This is my controller:

```
public function upload(){
    $this->load->helper('file');
    $fileName = time().$_FILES['file']['name'];

    $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH.'assets/'; //buat folder dengan nama assets di root folder
    $config['file_name'] = $fileName;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'xls|xlsx|csv';
    $config['max_size'] = 10000;

    $this->load->library('upload');
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if(! $this->upload->do_upload('file') )
    $this->upload->display_errors();

    $media = $this->upload->data('file');

    $inputFileName = $this->upload->data('full_path');
    //'.assets/'.$media['file_name'];   

    try {
            $inputFileType = IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
            $objReader = IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
            $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
        }

        $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
        $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
        $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

        for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){                  //  Read a row of data into an array                 
            $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,
                                            NULL,
                                            TRUE,
                                            FALSE);


            $data= array(

                "name"=> $rowData[0][1],
                "address"=> $rowData[0][2]

            );                

            $insert = $this->db->insert("info",$data);
           delete_files($config['file_path'],TRUE);                  
        }

}
```

I tried to do the same code for the second one, but i cant insert the data into the existing row, it always insert into new row.
Like this:

```
id | name | address | account | note
1     a       aa  
2     b       bb
3                       1       a
4                       2       bb
```

Can anyone help/give me idea how to join them all ?
Any help would be appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make second excel data like this

```
id | account | note
```

and update `account | note` column with id

Comment: i tried it but it gives me an error: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

UPDATE `info` SET `id` = 1, `note` = 1

Comment: or where should i put the update the column with the 'id'

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
```

if(isset($_POST["Import"])){

```
    $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];      


     if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
     {
        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
        while (($getData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
         {


           $sql = "INSERT into table (name,address) 
               values ('".$getData[0]."','".$getData[1]."')";
               $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            if(!isset($result))
            {
                echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                        alert(\"Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File.\");
                        window.location = \"index.php\"
                      </script>";       
            }
            else {
                  echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                    alert(\"CSV File has been successfully Imported.\");
                    window.location = \"index.php\"
                </script>";
            }
         }

         fclose($file); 
     }
}
```

?>